# How to return an iterator in entries, keys and values methods of a linked list?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement an `Array`-like linked list (same methods). I have the following two classes:

```
class Node {
  constructor(value, next_node=null, prev_node=null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next_node = next_node;
    this.prev_node = prev_node;
  }
}

class List {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement `values()`, `entries()` and `keys()` similar to of `Array`. My code:

```
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let current = this.head;
    return {
      next() {
        if (current) {
          let value = current.value;
          current = current.next;
          return {value: value, done: false};
        }
        return {done: true};
      }
    };
  }

  entries() {
    return this._entries();
  }

  keys() {
    return this._keys();
  }

  values() {
    return this._values();
  }

  * _entries() {
    var node = this.head;
    var counter = 0;
    while (node) {
      yield [counter,node.value];
      node = node.next_node;
      counter += 1;
    }
  }

  * _keys() {
    var node = this.head;
    var counter = 0;
    while (node) {
      yield counter;
      node = node.next_node;
      counter += 1;
    }
  }

  * _values() {
    var node = this.head;
    while (node) {
      yield node.value;
      node = node.next_node;
    }
  }
```

Comparing between `array.entries()` and `list.entries()` I see:

```
Object [Array Iterator] {}
Object [Generator] {}
```

I understand that there is a difference between an iterator and generator. Two questions:

1. Should I keep it as `Generator`? Why `Array` uses `Array Iterator` instead of a `Generator`?
2. If I should switch to an iterator, how it should be done for those methods? As you can see, I implemented `[Symbol.iterator]()`, but how do I use it in `entries()`, `keys()` and `values()`?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that there is a difference

Only in syntax, basically a generator is syntax sugar for implementing `Symbol.iterator`.  It makes it so that you don't need to worry about handling internal state like `done` etc, and just worry about how to `yield`.

> If I should switch to an iterator,

If you mean move away from using `generators`, as there both iterators internally anyway, then I would say no, `generators` are much easier to code and reason with, and implementing `Symbol.iterator` manually would be step backwards.

Also you can keep your code a little bit more DRY here, below is an example.

```js
class X {
  [Symbol.iterator]() { return this.values(); }
  *values() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  }
}

const x = new X();

//Both are iterators..
console.log('x.values() is iterator? ' +(Symbol.iterator in x.values()));
console.log('x is iterator? ' + (Symbol.iterator in x));

//Both work the same.
for (const a of x.values()) console.log(a);
for (const a of x) console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `[Symbol.iterator]` for `entries()`, you have to return a new object with `*[Symbol.iterator]`

```js
class List {
  constructor(min, max) {
    this.min = min
    this.max = max
  }

  entries() {
    const {
      min,
      max
    } = this
    return {
      *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let i = min; i <= max; i += 1) {
          yield i
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


const list = new List(2, 7)

console.log([...list.entries()])

for (const item of list.entries()) {
  console.log(item)
}
```